# Building Multilingual Windows CE 6.0 OS

Tags: embedded, platform-builder

I have buid a multilingual Windows CE 6.0 OS for differents roman european languages and several east asian: chinese, japanese and Korean.

To do this, I have followed the informations described par MS in the article "How to create a multilingual OS Design" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee491398.aspx).

On the targeted device (an AT61SAM9G45 dev kit), I can successfully swicth OS language through "Menu / Settings / Control Panel / Regional Settings", tab "User Interface Language". That's fine and work perfectly for european languages, chinese and for japanese.

But, when I switch to Korean, all characters are display as en empty square!

If a build an OS with only Korean, the characters are Ok. If a build an OS with Korean and Japanese only, all of them are displayed with empty squares (chinese was ok when alone or with roman languages)

Any idea to have korean fonts displayed in a multilingual OS?

Thank's

Comment: More stange: It works when I choose to set Korean as default language and add zero or only one east asian language (japanese or chinese)?!

Answer (score 0):

For a situation were several asian and roman languages are required, I believe it is required to customize the code pages of the OS image. There is some documentation about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834426.aspx#locplatform30_codepages